# Change palette color in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, color

I've modified this code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples:User+Interface/Split+Panel but I can't change the maps color pallet

This is the color pallet that I want to use:

```
var colorizedVis = {
min: -1.0,
max: 1.0,
palette: [
'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
'66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
'012E01', '011D01', '011301'
],
};
```

My code can be found here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/180bc2a78ec92b433ea7c369bb2e249c

or here:

Demonstrates before/after imagery comparison with a variety of dates.

Configure the imagery

```
  var images = {

  'L5_01_98' : ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_8DAY_EVI/19990101'),

  '5_04_08' : ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_8DAY_EVI/20080414'),
  '5_01_11' : ee.Image('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_8DAY_EVI/20110117'),

};


  var colorizedVis = {
    min: 0.0,
    max: 1.0,
    palette: [
      'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
      '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
      '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
    ],
  };
```

Set up the maps and control widgets

Create the left map, and have it display layer 0.

```
  var leftMap = ui.Map();
  leftMap.setControlVisibility(false);
  var leftSelector = addLayerSelector(leftMap, 0, 'top-left');
```

Create the right map, and have it display layer 1.

```
  var rightMap = ui.Map();
  rightMap.setControlVisibility(false);
  var rightSelector = addLayerSelector(rightMap, 1, 'top-right');
```

Adds a layer selection widget to the given map, to allow users to change
which image is displayed in the associated map.

```
  function addLayerSelector(mapToChange, defaultValue, position) {
  var label = ui.Label('Choose an image to visualize');
```

This function changes the given map to show the selected image.

```
  function updateMap(selection) {
  mapToChange.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(images[selection]));
  }
```

Configure a selection dropdown to allow the user to choose between images, and set the map to update when a user makes a selection.

```
  var select = ui.Select({items: Object.keys(images), onChange: updateMap});
  select.setValue(Object.keys(images)[defaultValue], true);

  var controlPanel =
  ui.Panel({widgets: [label, select], style: {position: position}});

  mapToChange.add(controlPanel);
  }
```

Tie everything together

Create a SplitPanel to hold the adjacent, linked maps.

```
  var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
    firstPanel: leftMap,
    secondPanel: rightMap,
    wipe: true,
    style: {stretch: 'both'}
  });
```

Set the SplitPanel as the only thing in the UI root.

```
  ui.root.widgets().reset([splitPanel]);
  var linker = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap]);
  leftMap.setCenter(-65.49522105694524,-24.717770902233013, 13);
```

[image: Grey Pallet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style the images in your dictionary with the `visualize` method. Make a styling function that calls on your visualization arguments (includes the palette you want) and apply it to each image. Here is the function:

```js
function styleImg(img){
  return ee.Image(img
    .visualize(colorizedVis)
    .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames()))}
```

See lines 8-34: https://code.earthengine.google.com/77633bcde657e10a829a9aa2a83550de